# In SQL Server, how to set a minute

Tags: sql-server

I have a date that will come from a table columns. I just want to SET the minute portions to a different value. That value will be in the `@PreviousMinuteForGapFill` variable.

How?

I tried `DATEADD` but that adds the value.

```
 SET @ModifiedStartDateTime = 
         DATEADD(MINUTE, @PreviousMinuteForGapFill, @ModifiedStartDateTime)
```

Comment: You should really supply what Types and values are in those Variables. And also what is the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
declare @test datetime = '20160101 10:20:30'
declare @PreviousMinuteForGapFill int = 5

select dateadd(minute, @PreviousMinuteForGapFill, dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, @test), @test))
```

the result will be

> 01/01/2016  10:05:30